# Tableview with fetchedResultsController not updating new content until app restart or view gets reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My tableview isnt being populated by data being pulled in nsfetchedresultscontroller until the app is restarted or i go to another view controller and back. I've never had this problem before, very weird.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 60, 0);

    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }


    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refresh addTarget:self
                action:@selector(refresh)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refresh;

    UITableViewController *tableVC = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [tableVC setTableView:self.tableView];
    tableVC.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;

    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, -60.0f)
                                          animated:YES];
    [self getPosts];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

getPosts pulls in all the posts for the tableview and saves them to coredata.

```
-(void)getPosts
{
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [self.postsController getPostsFeedWithCompletion:^(BOOL complete, NSArray *posts) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } failure:^(NSString *message) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        ALAlertBanner *alert = [ALAlertBanner alertBannerForView:self.view
                                                           style:ALAlertBannerStyleFailure
                                                        position:ALAlertBannerPositionTop
                                                           title:@"Error"
                                                        subtitle:@"Error retrieving posts, please try again."];
        [alert show];

    }];
}
```

The getPostsFeedWithCompletion method:

```
-(void)getPostsFeedWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL complete, NSArray *posts))complete
                          failure:(void (^)(NSString *message))failure

{
    [[APIManager sharedManager] getPath:@"posts/feed"
                             parameters:nil
                                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                    DLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);

                                    NSArray __block *posts;

                                    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
                                        posts = [self createPosts:responseObject[@"posts"] inContext:localContext];
                                    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                        if(complete){
                                            complete(YES, posts);
                                        }
                                    }];

                                }
                                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                    DLog(@"error: %@", error);
                                    if(failure){
                                        failure(@"Error retrieving posts");
                                    }
                                }];
}
```

heres the nsfetchedresultscontroller instantiation

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Post" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray  *following = [[SessionManager getInstance].currentLoggedInUser.follows allObjects];

    NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"account IN %@", following]];
    [predicateArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"expiration > %@", now]];

    NSCompoundPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateArray];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:filterPredicate];
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];


    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"expiration" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:context
                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Heres is the log from the MagicalRecord Save:

```
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffcea601bd0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ffcea601bd0): *** UNNAMED ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffcea601bd0) → Save Parents? 1
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffcea601bd0) → Save Synchronously? 1
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7ffcea601bd0) Context UNNAMED is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 22 inserted objects
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffceba008f0) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ffceba008f0): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffceba008f0) → Save Parents? 1
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffceba008f0) → Save Synchronously? 1
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7ffceba008f0) Context DEFAULT is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 22 inserted objects
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffcea746c10) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ffcea746c10): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffcea746c10) → Save Parents? 1
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x7ffcea746c10) → Save Synchronously? 1
[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x7ffcea746c10) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 22 inserted objects
_70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke21(0x7ffcea746c10) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x7ffcea746c10): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
```

Comment: My guess: you save data in a background managed object context and don't merge them into the main thread's context?

Comment: @MichałCiuba I am creating the data on a background thread but saving  with [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait] which is what I've done a thousand times and never had this problem

Comment: I'm not familiar with MagicalRecord, but will this cause merging the data to the main thread's context? That context is used by the NSFRC. Do you implement `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods? And also, what are these lines for: `UITableViewController *tableVC = [[UITableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [tableVC setTableView:self.tableView];`? As far as I know two controllers can't share their view.

Comment: @MichałCiuba its not a tableviewcontroller its a uiviewcontroller with a tableview.  that code adds the refreshcontrol

Comment: Looks like none of the NSFetchedResultsController Delegate Methods are being called at all.

Comment: Can you give us some basic information about specifically how `getPostsFeedWithCompletion:` works? Is the background context tied directly to the persistent store coordinator, or does it have the main thread context as its parent context? Does it merge changes into the main context appropriately if it ties directly to the store coordinator? If you don't know, which MagicalRecord calls you use in that method would at least hint at that information and help us solve it.

Comment: @AndyRiordan I added it to the question above.  Im using [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock]

Comment: Are you calling reloadData on the tableview anywhere?

Comment: @Pahnev no, the NSFETCHEDRESULTSCONTROLLER handles that.. Is supposed to handle that.

Comment: How is `self.tableView` instantiated and incorporated into the view hierarchy?  And why do you call `[super viewDidLoad]` twice?

Comment: Also, how are the tableView delegate and datasource set?

Comment: Based on the behaviour you describe I think "Is supposed" is the key here. If it is reloading the tableview it´s doing it at the wrong time and there´s nothing to show.

Comment: @pbasdf [super viewdidload] was in there twice because of an accident, removed it, no change.  Tableview is added in the storyboard wired through outlets to delegate/datasource which isnt the problem

Comment: @Pahnev the tableview gets realoaded when the FRC delegate methods are called after the context gets updated.  This never happens.  That's the problem.

Comment: Is `following` array empty in `fetchedResultsController` method when the issue occurs? Also, does changing  `NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];` to `MR_defaultContext` help? How do you setup your Core Data stack and contexts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my predicate.
 NSArray  *following was being hard set in the getter for the FRC but its empty until the getPosts api call completes.